# Why is ResponseMessage.Content consistently empty after an await PostAsJsonAsync request?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

We are posting a "maintenanceEvent" to an API which consistently returns [] in ResponseMessage.Content. I'd need some expert guidance in case the code I wrote here is faulty.

```
private async Task SendMaintenanceEvent(object maintenanceEvent, MaintenanceEventType maintenanceEventType)
{
    string endpointAddress = "TheEndpointURI";
    string credentials = "OurCredentials";
    string credentialsBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(credentials));

    // Convert the maintenanceEvent object to consumable JSON, then encode it to a StringContent object.
    this.responseInfo.MaintenanceEventAsJSON = System.Web.Helpers.Json.Encode(maintenanceEvent);
    StringContent stringContent = new StringContent(this.responseInfo.MaintenanceEventAsJSON, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(endpointAddress);
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", credentialsBase64);
        this.responseInfo.AuthorizationHeader = httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization.ToString();
        this.responseInfo.EndpointUri = httpClient.BaseAddress.AbsoluteUri;

        // The async post.
        this.responseInfo.ResponseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(access.EndpointDirectory, stringContent).ConfigureAwait(false);

        this.responseInfo.ResponseStatusCode = (int)this.responseInfo.ResponseMessage.StatusCode;

        // Consistently returns true so long as my credentials are valid.
        // When the auth credentials are invalid, this returns false.
        if (this.responseInfo.ResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            // I expect to see some data from the service.
            this.responseInfo.ResponseContent = this.responseInfo.ResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Try/Catch blocks and some company specific info is omitted.  The responseInfo object above is just a model with some properties to collect information from this method, so we can record the event.

Where I suspect a problem may be, is in the code below the PostAsJsonAsync command. But I'm at a loss for what to do there.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is ResponseContent really of type Task<string>? If it's of type string you need to await the ReadAsStringAsync() in that line.

Comment: Thanks sellotape. If I do this, then how can I assign the result to a string?  I'm reading up on async and was watching a Stephen Taub presentation on it.  I just tried this and got an implicit conversion warning:  var responseContentString = await this.responseInfo.ResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
this.responseInfo.ResponseContent = responseContentString.ToString();

Comment: It's not a type of Task<string>.  So I tried this:  Task<string> response = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(access.EndpointDirectory, stringContent).ConfigureAwait(false);  And now Intellisense shows, "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string>'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This (slightly adjusted) is what you want to do (substitute your own variables as needed):

```
using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    // ...
    HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(access.EndpointDirectory, stringContent).ConfigureAwait(false);
    // ...
    string responseBody = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    // ...
}
```

I.e. you must await `ReadAsStringAsync()` to get the actual content.

For completeness, note that `HttpResponseMessage` and `HttpResponseMessage.Content` are `IDisposable`.

Comment: sellotape, thanks so much for your help. I've got to jump offline for the day, but will be back in the morning to give this a shot. Thanks for the IDisposable tip.  Is the responseBody line guaranteed execute *after* the responseMessage line completes?  So sorry, as async is something I haven't dealt with in .NET before.  I was wondering if it needed to be in some downstream delegate. Thanks for your patience!

Comment: "Is the responseBody line guaranteed execute after the responseMessage line completes" - assuming you mean is there no chance it tries to execute before the first line is finished, then yes, absolutely (with the first await there like that).

Comment: Thanks for your help sellotape!